# Cannot update text in EditText inside onActivityResult

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

I am trying to use  Voice Recognition on Android. Following is my code.

This is the code of the Button that is responsible to start speech recognition.
    speak.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "City Name Please?");
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
    }});
```

Here is a onActivityResult method.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        ArrayList<String> matches_Text = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        Log.v("Results", matches_Text.get(0).toString());

//Update EditText cityname here

        String normalized_cityname = matches_Text.get(0).toString().trim();
        normalized_cityname = normalized_cityname.replace(" ","%20");
        try {
            getResponseString("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+normalized_cityname+"&units=metric", true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The code worked ok but there are two problems I am encountering now and I am afraid that they may be related.

1. If I try to update text in an `EditText` instance `cityname` using `cityname.setText(matches_Text.get(0).toString())`, it crashes the app.
2. If I hit the `speak` button now, the google voice dialog comes up but shows `can't reacg google at the moment`.

Please suggest what can I do?

Adding the `getResponseString` method also.

```
public void getResponseString(String Url, boolean IsCalledOnVoiceInput) throws IOException, JSONException {
        String temperature="";
        String city;
        String country;
        String weather_main, weather_description;
        MyAsyncTask xxx = new MyAsyncTask();
        try {
            String responseString = xxx.execute(Url).get();

            TextView txtTemp = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_temp);
            TextView txtCity = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_CityName);
            TextView txtWeatherMain = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            TextView txtWeatherDescription = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);

            JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(responseString);
            JSONObject main  = reader.getJSONObject("main");

            temperature = main.getString("temp");
            Log.v("temperarure",temperature);

            city = reader.getString("name");
            Log.v("city",city);

            JSONObject sys  = reader.getJSONObject("sys");
            country = sys.getString("country");
            Log.v("country",country);

            JSONArray weather = reader.getJSONArray("weather");
            JSONObject weather_obj = weather.getJSONObject(0);
            weather_main = weather_obj.getString("main");
            weather_description = weather_obj.getString("description");

            txtTemp.setText(temperature+" °C");
            txtCity.setText(city+" ("+country+")");
            txtWeatherMain.setText(weather_main);
            txtWeatherDescription.setText(weather_description);

            if(IsCalledOnVoiceInput)
                Speak_Weather_Data(city,temperature,weather_main,weather_description);



        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Here is the log output

```
    12-24 13:36:06.050  12164-12164/samarth.learning.http D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
12-24 13:36:06.300  12164-12164/samarth.learning.http D/Network﹕ Network
12-24 13:36:06.300  12164-12164/samarth.learning.http V/Lat﹕ 28.8331443
12-24 13:36:06.300  12164-12164/samarth.learning.http V/Long﹕ 78.7717138
12-24 13:36:06.360  12164-12164/samarth.learning.http D/libEGL﹕ loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno.so
12-24 13:36:06.370  12164-12164/samarth.learning.http D/libEGL﹕ loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno.so
12-24 13:36:06.380  12164-12164/samarth.learning.http D/libEGL﹕ loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so
12-24 13:36:06.380  12164-12164/samarth.learning.http I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:316>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (CL4169980)
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: 17.01.10.SPL
    Build Date: 11/04/13 Mon
    Local Branch:
    Remote Branch:
    Local Patches:
    Reconstruct Branch:
12-24 13:36:06.430  12164-12164/samarth.learning.http D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
12-24 13:36:06.531  12164-12164/samarth.learning.http E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
12-24 13:36:06.531  12164-12164/samarth.learning.http E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
12-24 13:36:08.232  12164-12164/samarth.learning.http W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
12-24 13:36:18.844  12164-12164/samarth.learning.http V/Results﹕ new delhi
12-24 13:36:18.844  12164-12164/samarth.learning.http D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
12-24 13:36:18.844  12164-12164/samarth.learning.http W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4157c8b0)
12-24 13:36:18.854  12164-12164/samarth.learning.http E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1234, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {samarth.learning.http/samarth.learning.http.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3462)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3505)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:150)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1346)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at samarth.learning.http.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:160)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5322)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3458)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3505)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:150)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1346)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-24 13:36:22.558  12164-12164/samarth.learning.http I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 12164 SIG: 9
```

Comment: show getresponsestring method...

Comment: Done adding the method.

Comment: So the log statement, where you print the string, doesn't crash, but if you use that same string in cityname.setText, it does crash? Does the string look like you expect in the log? What is the stack crash? Are you sure your cityname field is set correctly?

Comment: Yes, the Log shows `Results: Heres what I speak` always and then crash saying the `VM was shutdown`.

Comment: Can you post the log that shows the crash?

Comment: Oh! you are using the AsyncTask wrong. You cannot make network operation like this.

Comment: Can you please correct me? Also I have noticed that if I restart my device, the Google voice recognition worked just once, and I will have to restart again.

Comment: @tasomaniac what am I doing wrong? Please tell.

Comment: Using AsyncTask with `xxx.execute(Url).get()` is wrong. You can check this link out http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html

Comment: I changed that. Still the same issue. I moved all the code from getResponseString to the doInBackground method and implemented the onPostExecute also. It recognnizes voice but then exits saying `thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4157c8b0)`

Comment: @SamarthAgarwal i think `matches_Text` is sometimes NULL?! how about adding an `if(matches_Text  == null){Log.v("Results","matches_Text   is NULL!"); return;}`

Comment: @SamarthAgarwal add above code just after `ArrayList<String> matches_Text = da...`

Comment: I did that. Now Google Voice Input Dialog shows up, but then after one attempt says that GOOGLE CAN'T BE REACHED AT THE MOMENT.

Comment: I don't know what to do now. Now even Google Now is not working on the device. Is it possible that this code messed it up?

Comment: Well the code just started working and now its showing the following in the log as well
`Sucessfully bound to com.google.android.tts`

Working fine but not following the `maches_text==null` condition ever.

Comment: @SamarthAgarwal it could be something related to network? or the service is not working probably, mean at google's side?! could be ?

Comment: Yes I was concluding the same.

Comment: @Yazan Post your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this what you mean?

i think matches_Text is sometimes NULL?! how about adding an

```
if(matches_Text == null){
   Log.v("Results","matches_Text is NULL!"); 
   return;
}
```

add above code just after `ArrayList<String> matches_Text = da...`

Comment: Yes, I guess that helped me.